# Flutter always restarting and not hot reloading

Tags: flutter

I installed Flutter 2.2 on Windows 10 and added the Flutter extension to VSCode. I have no problem running the boilerplate code that gets created by the Flutter extension when starting a new project.

In the code there is a comment that encourages you to try out hot reloading. See the code below, where you change the Primary Swatch to a different colour than blue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  String name = 'Paps';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_down),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that it always restart the application on change, rather than hot reload.

I have tried F5 for debug, and also Ctrl-F5 to start without debugging. I also tried `flutter run` from the command line and then pressing `r`. The output is always the same:

```
Restarted application in 490ms.
Restarted application in 224ms.
Restarted application in 218ms.
```

So every time I make a change to my code, the application state is lost. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you running it on web?

Comment: Yip, yes, I tried on both Chrome and Edge. Both give the same problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hot reload not supported on web right now. You can refer this [FAQ](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web#does-hot-reload-work-with-a-web-app)

Comment: (! Time Saving !)

Answer (score 1):

Actually flutter in web doesn't support hot reloading until now:
If you want hot reloading for time efficiency use a android or ios emulator . You can also use a low spec emulator like ld player:
https://www.ldplayer.net/

Answer (score 0):

You Should Downgrade Your Flutter Version the commands are here

In the Flutter install directory execute

```
git checkout v0.1.9

then run

flutter doctor
```

You can check which versions are available in the Flutter GitHub repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter